# Content not showing in there correct module positions

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a controller that shows modules for my each position

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [layout_module_id] => 1
            [layout_id] => 1
            [module_id] => 1
            [position] => column_left
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [layout_module_id] => 2
            [layout_id] => 1
            [module_id] => 2
            [position] => column_left
            [sort_order] => 2
        )

)
```

Above currently I have only two modules set and the are in the position of column left.

Because the position views are out side of the foreach loop they are picking up that module even though not set for that position? As shown in image.

[image]

[image]

> **Question:** How can I make sure that the module will only display in its set position view.

```
public function index() {
    $layout_id = $this->getlayoutID($this->router->class);

    $modules = $this->getlayoutsmodule($layout_id);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($modules);
    echo "</pre>";

    $data['modules'] = array();

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $this->load->library('module/question_help');
        $data['modules'][] = $this->load->view('module/question_help', $this->question_help->set(), TRUE);  
    }

    // Position Views
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->view('column_left', $data, TRUE);
    $data['column_right'] = $this->load->view('column_right', $data, TRUE);
    $data['content_top'] = $this->load->view('content_top', $data, TRUE);
    $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->view('content_bottom', $data, TRUE);

    // Main view
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}

public function getlayoutsmodule($layout_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('layouts_module');
    $this->db->where('layout_id', $layout_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }   
}
```

Each of the position views have the same foreach loop

```
<?php if ($modules) { ?>
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
<?php echo $module;?>
<?php } ?>  
<?php }?>
```

main view

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $column_left; ?>

    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
    <?php echo $content_top; ?>
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

    <div id="body">
    <p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>

    <p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
    <code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>

    <p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
    <code>application/controllers/Welcome.php</code>

    <p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>

    <?php echo $content_bottom; ?>  
    </div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put `foreach` block of `getModuleLayouts` method outside query, change `or_where()` query builder method with `where()`, instead of returning `$query->result_array()`, set it into new keys of new array that would follow foreach loop that returns array outside the loop. Try and check if working this way.

Comment: @Tpojka you have an example?

Comment: Well, I don't have you app installed if you ask for that, how do you mean? :) I think that need to be changed there. Have you tried that suggestion? Is anything different there?

Comment: @Tpojka solved now answered below

Comment: Good. To avoid [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), You can pull out `$data['modules'] = array();` outside (before) switch statement because you are  breaking execution everytime condition is met and staring with an empty array.
And also, `if` block in each case you can set into `getlayoutsmodule()` method since same code is used in every case there. Just set what that method should return to let you include in view.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working I have had to use a foreach switch statement

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $layout_id = $this->getlayoutID($this->router->class);

        $column_left = '';
        $column_right = '';
        $content_top = '';
        $content_bottom = '';
        $position = array('column_left', 'column_right', 'content_top', 'content_bottom');

        foreach ($position as $key) {

            switch ($key) {
                case 'column_left':

                    $data['modules'] = array();

                    $layout_module_results = $this->getlayoutsmodule($layout_id, 'column_left');

                    if (!empty($layout_module_results)) {
                        foreach ($layout_module_results as $layout_module_result) {
                            $data['modules'][] = array(
                                'position' => $layout_module_result['position']
                            );
                        }   
                    }   

                    $column_left = $this->load->view('column_left', $data, TRUE);

                    break;

                case 'column_right':

                    $data['modules'] = array();

                    $layout_module_results = $this->getlayoutsmodule($layout_id, 'column_right');

                    if (!empty($layout_module_results)) {
                        foreach ($layout_module_results as $layout_module_result) {
                            $data['modules'][] = array(
                                'position' => $layout_module_result['position']
                            );
                        }   
                    }   

                    $column_right = $this->load->view('column_right', $data, TRUE);

                    break;

                case 'content_top':

                    $data['modules'] = array();

                    $layout_module_results = $this->getlayoutsmodule($layout_id, 'content_top');

                    if (!empty($layout_module_results)) {
                        foreach ($layout_module_results as $layout_module_result) {
                            $data['modules'][] = array(
                                'position' => $layout_module_result['position']
                            );
                        }   
                    }   

                    $content_top = $this->load->view('content_top', $data, TRUE);

                    break;

                case 'content_bottom':

                    $data['modules'] = array(); 

                    $layout_module_results = $this->getlayoutsmodule($layout_id, 'content_bottom');

                    if (!empty($layout_module_results)) {
                        foreach ($layout_module_results as $layout_module_result) {
                            $data['modules'][] = array(
                                'position' => $layout_module_result['position']
                            );
                        }   
                    }   

                    $content_bottom = $this->load->view('content_bottom', $data, TRUE);

                    break;
            }

        }

        $data['column_left'] = $column_left;
        $data['column_right'] = $column_right;
        $data['content_top'] = $content_top;
        $data['content_bottom'] = $content_bottom;

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```